"than was previously supposed" - I don't understand why we leaving "was" here is correct
I've read this sentence:

Their discovery means that archaic humans, who left Africa 1.5 million years earlier than modern people, survived far longer into recent times than was previously supposed.

(New York Times)
I wonder why the finite verb "was" can exist here. My current understanding is that we either use a full clause, like this:

Their discovery means that archaic humans survived far longer into recent times than (the time) it was previously supposed.
OR a phrase, like this:
Their discovery means that archaic humans survived far longer into recent times than previously supposed. (a past participle phrase)

But we shouldn't mix both. So why the "was"? I suspect some kind of ellipsis from a full clause, but I'm not sure. Because if it's an ellipsis, shouldn't the "was" be deleted as well?

It is ellipsis (of the auxiliary verb was and dummy subject it). See this usage chart showing that until 60 years ago, we normally did include the auxiliary.

You might find something useful in this earlier question.

@FumbleFingers Your usage chart is cherry-picking. You cannot make sweeping generalizations about the  auxiliary based on one collocation. This one shows just the opposite: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+previously+supposed%2Cthan+was+previously+supposed&year_start=1822&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=2  and so does this one: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+previously+believed%2Cthan+was+previously+believed&year_start=1822&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=2

and this one https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+previously+expected%2Cthan+was+previously+expected&year_start=1822&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=2 and this one https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+previously+hoped%2Cthan+was+previously+hoped&year_start=1822&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=2 and this one https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+previously+enjoyed%2Cthan+was+previously+enjoyed&year_start=1822&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=2

@TimR: You're getting confused. ALL your charts AS WELL AS MINE show that auxiliary was is increasingly elided in recent decades, regardless of whether the primary verb is as was previously supposed / thought / believed / hoped / enjoyed / whatever. That's to say until 60 years ago, we normally did include the auxiliary, like I said.

The elided and non-elided variants of these constructions are BOTH in decline.  We did elide more in the past as well.  The variant with than was had its heyday in the 19th c.

"than was" is the more old-fashioned construction. That it is used today even as much (or as little) as it is,  is because it was often taught that these constructions were flawed without it.

Consider:

The car gets fewer miles per gallon of fuel than (was) previously advertised.

The forms of BE can often be omitted (ellipted) in English without the ellipsis interfering with communication.
The implicit or tacit subject of "was" must be a nominal form of the verb-phrase found in the matrix clause.
That the form "than was" is used there at all is the result of a misguided educational campaign that lasted more than a century.
If "than was" is used in a comparative clause, there's a very good chance the speaker was university educated or that the text was edited by someone who had been taught that "than was" was proper despite the language heading away from it.

I don't buy that "misguided educational campaign". In at least some contexts, failure to explicitly specify the subject (even if only with a "dummy it", as per my comment under the Q) could lead to ambiguity. Feasibly dummy it should always be the default if not specified, but I wouldn't like to bet my life on that. And if was is also elided, it's not obvious to me the full underlying text couldn't be ...than they previously supposed, or ...than was previously supposed by me. Just because we shorten more often today doesn't mean longer is "undesirable".

@FumbleFingers I don't even address dummy "it" in my answer. I am contrasting  "than was previously supposed" vs "than previously supposed".  If you want to give an answer about "dummy it" being needed in some circumstances, I'd be interested to see the answer.

As I said in my original comment, the implied subject of the verb supposed in OP's example is the dummy "it" (where it's possible to elide just "it", OR to elide both "it" and "was", but it's not possible to elide just "was"). You can't really talk about eliding "was" without mentioning that "it" must also have been elided.

I might write my own answer later, if I get around to it.

@FumbleFingers Re your assertion that "You can't really talk about eliding 'was' without mentioning that 'it' must also have been elided", see BillJ's answer here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373692/where-is-the-subject-in-as-was-traditional-for-unmarried-women

That's a different construction, where as was traditional involves a straightforward adjective, with no possibility of an unstated agent doing the "traditioning". It's perfectly natural to delete both subject and object in this OP's ...then previously supposed. But for the last century or two it's been at least "unusual" to include a dummy "it" in the linked example (As it was traditional for unmarried women, Jane lived at home). And I'm not convinced it's even syntactically valid to remove the verb - As traditional for unmarried women... doesn't sound good to me.

The constructions are the same in key respects. To you point about unstated agents, I think it takes a while for the past participle to achieve adjective status, and the agent dissolves at different speeds for different speakers and dialects
